# 'Edit Billing Address', 'Change Password', 'Payment Method' forms on Dashboard tab

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

I'm just starting to learn how to theme WooCommerce and have tried my best to find a solution to my problem.

Basically, I want to display 'my-account/edit-address/billing', the Change Password, and Add Payment Method forms on 'my-account/dashboard'.

I was hoping to divide the 'Edit Billing Address' into 2 sections, maybe there's a way to call individual fields instead of the whole form?

Here's to illustrate what I want to achieve:

```
My Account - Dashboard


{Edit Billing Address part 1}

billing_first_name | billing_last_name | billing_phone | billing_email

submit_button


{Edit Billing Address part 2}

billing_company | billing_address_1

submit_button


{Change Password fieldset}


{Display existing / add payment card}
```

Comment: The billing address here will only be used as a forced shipping address. Also, I thought that if we use Stripe, the data won't be saved on our servers?

Comment: Then `{Display existing / add payment card}` should not appear in "my account", as this will save sensible data on WooCommerce. Stripe payment gateway will handle everything related to customer payment card and related options in checkout zone during payment process.

Comment: We have decided to forego Stripe and just go with card/cash on delivery. Our only need now is to be able to display Edit Billing Address form fields individually on the Dashboard tab.